# Spring security ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS form login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-3

I want to connect Spring Security to my project.

```java
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    @SneakyThrows
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

After starting the web server, it gives `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` when accessing any of the pages.
There are no controllers.

Deleted controllers, tried adding `request.anyRequest("/login").permitAll()`.

Comment: please update your question with full DEBUG or TRACE logs and include more information than `accessing any of the pages` what pages, how, what does the request look like. If you expect anyone to put effort into your question, you should at least at a minimum put some effort into it yourself.

Comment: Do you have a custom login page ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this problem(`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` ) happen when you have a custom login page.

AS @Toerktumlare suggested you have to enable `DEBUG` mode and see the trace. After it you will see that something like this.

[image]

It mean that static resources where you have login page also is under security and you have to declare a request Matchers that give access to everyone there.
The `securityFilterChain` will have next one body:

```
  @Bean
  @SneakyThrows
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
          request.requestMatchers("/WEB-INF/**").permitAll();
            request.anyRequest().authenticated();

        })
        .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    return http.build();
  }
```

A reference to the same problem you can see here [13285](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13285)